# To recognition the face

Tags: python, face-recognition, pylance

I am write the code to recognition the face and mark attendence but so Error come and when i run the project the camere are open but not recogition the face the give face are stick on the camera screen.
and the following error is are has follw:

```
File "g:\Attendence System\face_recognition.py", line 93, in face_recog
    img=recognize(img,clf,faceCascade)
  File "g:\Attendence System\face_recognition.py", line 82, in recognize
    coord = draw_boundray(img,faceCascade,1.1,10,(255,255,255),"Face",clf)
  File "g:\Attendence System\face_recognition.py", line 59, in draw_boundray
    name="+".join(name)
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

and some varible i declare but It's not access the given error is ret is not accessed pylance
plz help with this problem.

[image: It's show ret is not accessed pylance]

[image: is not accessed pylance]

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np


class Face_Recognition:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry("1530x790+0+0")
        self.root.title("Face Recognition System")

        lbl_title=Label(self.root,text="FACE RECOGNITION",font=("time new roman",35,"bold"),bg="white",fg="green")
        lbl_title.place(x=0,y=0,width=1530,height=45)

        #1st image
        img_top=Image.open(r"Images\workingonface.jpg")
        img_top=img_top.resize((650,700),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.photoimg_top=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_top)

        f_lbl=Label(self.root,image=self.photoimg_top)
        f_lbl.place(x=0,y=55,width=650,height=700)

        #2st image
        img_bottom=Image.open(r"Images\facial_recognition_system_identi.jpg")
        img_bottom=img_bottom.resize((950,700),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.photoimg_bottom=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_bottom)

        f_lbl=Label(self.root,image=self.photoimg_bottom)
        f_lbl.place(x=650,y=55,width=950,height=700)

        #buttom
        b1_1=Button(f_lbl,text="Face Recognition",cursor="hand2",command=self.face_recog,font=("time new roman",18,"bold"),bg="darkgreen",fg="white")
        b1_1.place(x=365,y=620,width=210,height=40)

    #==================Face recognition=============

    def face_recog(self):
        def draw_boundray(img,classifier,scaleFactor,minNeighbors,color,text,clf):
            gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            features = classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_image,scaleFactor,minNeighbors)

            coord=[]

            for(x,y,w,h) in features:
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)
                id,predict=clf.predict(gray_image[y:y+h,x:x+w])
                confidence=int((100*(1-predict/300)))

                con = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',username='root',password='',database='face_recognition')
                my_courser=con.cursor()

                my_courser.execute("select Name from students where StudentID="+str(id))
                name=my_courser.fetchone()
                name="+".join(name)

                my_courser.execute("select Roll from students where StudentID="+str(id))
                r=my_courser.fetchone()
                r="+".join(r)

                my_courser.execute("select Dep from students where StudentID="+str(id))
                d=my_courser.fetchone()
                d="+".join(d)

                if confidence>77:
                    cv2.putText(img,f"Roll No:{r}",(x,y-55),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,255),3)
                    cv2.putText(img,f"Name:{name}",(x,y-30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,255),3)
                    cv2.putText(img,f"Department:{d}",(x,y-5),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,255),3)
                else:
                    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),3)
                    cv2.putText(img,"Unknown face",(x,y-5),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,255),3)
                
                coord=[x,y,w,y]

            return coord

        def recognize(img,clf,faceCascade):
            coord = draw_boundray(img,faceCascade,1.1,10,(255,255,255),"Face",clf)
            return img

        faceCascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
        clf=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
        clf.read("classifier.xml")

        video_cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while True:
            ret,img=video_cap.read()
            img=recognize(img,clf,faceCascade)
            cv2.imshow("Welcome To Face Recognition",img)

            if cv2.waitKey(1)==13:
                break
        video_cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj=Face_Recognition(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: text are given below

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue definitely is not a face recognition one:

```
name=my_courser.fetchone()
name="+".join(name)
```

Your error means that `name` is not iterable as it shoud be if `my_courser.fetchone()` returns something but None.
You may try:

```
name=my_courser.fetchone()
if name:
    name="+".join(name)
```

And do the same at the next similar blocks ahead.